# Shell script to loop over all files in a folder and pick them in numerical order

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have the following code to loop through the files of a folder. Files are named 1.txt, 2.txt all the way to 15.txt

```sh
for file in .solutions/*; do 
    if [ -f "$file" ]; then 
        echo "test case ${file##*/}:"
        cat ./testcases/${file##*/}
        echo
        echo "result:"
        cat "$file"
        echo
        echo
    fi 
done
```

My issue I get 1.txt then 10.txt to 15.txt displayed.

I would like it to be displayed in **numerical order** instead of **lexicographical order**, in other words I want the loop to iterate though the files in numerical order.  Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
ls *.txt | sort -n
```

This would solve the problem, provided `.solutions` is a directory and no directory is named with an extension `.txt`.

and if you want complete accuracy,

```
ls -al *.txt | awk '$0 ~ /^-/ {print $9}' | sort -n
```

Update:

As per your edits,
you can simply do this,

```
ls | sort -n |
    while read file
    do
        #do whatever you want here
        :
    done
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't answer my question as it have no impact on the ouptut of my script. The idea is that the loop should iterate through each files in numerical order.

Comment: @SoyänChardon, check it now

Answer (score 1):

Looping through `ls` is usually a bad idea since file names can have newlines in them. Redirecting using process substitution instead of piping the results will keep the scope the same (variables you set will stay after the loop).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    echo "test case ${file##*/}:"
    cat ./testcases/${file##*/}
    echo
    echo "result:"
    cat "$file"
    echo
    echo
done < <(find '.solutions/' -name '*.txt' -type f -print0 | sort -nz)
```

Setting IFS to `""` keeps the leading/trailing spaces, `-r` to stop backslashes messing stuff up, and `-d ''` to use NUL instead of newlines.

The `find` command looks normal files `-type f`, so the `if [ -f "$file" ]` check isn't needed. It finds `-name '*.txt'` files in `'.solutions/'` and prints them `-print0` NUL terminated.

The `sort` command accepts NUL terminated strings with the `-z` option, and sorts them numerically with `-n`.